# Is there a way to access the runtime arguments in the post-action script for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, arguments

Basically, what I would like to do is to first set the arguments passed on launch by editing the scheme of current target, then access those arguments in the script, which I use as the post-action script.

I know I could use many build settings variables such as PRODUCT_NAME, but still can't find one to access arguments. If it is not possible, is there a walk-around? One awkward way I am thinking is to output the arguments to a txt file in my main.mm, then read them in my script. Thanks.